# What happens when a symbol exists in system library, and multiple 3rd-party libraries when linking a program?

Tags: dll, linker, shared-libraries

The next revision of the POSIX / Single Unix Specification standard is expected to [include](https://www.austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=1294) a C compiler that is capable of producing shared objects / dynamic libraries.

One of the comments caught my attention, and I'm quoting the essence of it here:

> ... some dynamic linker implementations require that an exhaustive list of exported symbols ...

I've also heard of `__declspec(dllexport)` in Microsoft toolchains, and likes.

The current wording for the next revision of the standard doesn't seem to include any capability to specify individual symbols for export, nor do they explicitly specify behaviors with regard to duplicate symbols. And I'm worried that I can't suppress the exporting of symbols internal to the implementation of my library.

On the platforms I checked - MacOSX and GNU/Linux, using the native linker to produce executable from static and shared objects, I observe:

1. linker giving duplicate symbols errors with static libraries.
2. when running the built program as a process, it invokes the one defined in the first dynamic library specified on the command line for linking with the executable program file.

My question being: is such behavior specified? In the POSIX/SUS standard? In ABI standard? In OS vendor documents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my personal guess.

Toolchain linkers are right to emit errors for duplicate symbols, but only when they can link-edit the file containing the symbol. In this respect, shared object are not link-editable to toolchain linkers - they're only link-editable at runtime by executable dynamic linker interpreter program. All toolchain linkers do is to include the information about the dynamic library in whatever product it outputs.

Next, dynamic linking is specified in both POSIX/SUS (`dlopen`) and [System V gABI](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/elf/gabi41.pdf#page=98), where the various loading order is defined, among which, "load order" is one of them. As specified in POSIX/SUS, load order involves not only the order in which `dlopen` is called, but also the dynamic libraries specified to the toolchain linker.

Due to these 2 reasons, we observe static objects giving errors while shared objects giving the first come first served behavior.